# Наложение текстуры

Tags: opengl

Добрый вечер!

Такой вопрос: рисую сферу

```
gluSphere(quadratic, 700.0f, 32, 32);
```

На нее накладывается текстура, но радиус очень большой и возникает необходимость "замостить" сферу текстурой. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете применять текстуры к этой сфере обычным способом (glGenTextures, glBindTexture, glTexEnvf, glTexParameterf, etc). Но есть одна тонкость: вы почти не можете управлять этим наложением: соотношение текстурных координат и вершин сферы не контролируются. Разве что вы можете применять некоторые транфсормации к текстуре модифицируя матрицу текстурной трансформации, но этого не всегда хватает. Ещё можно попытаться применить шейдеры (сгодятся как вершинные, так и пиксельные), но всё равно могут возникнуть сложности. В конечном итоге вы не можете пропихнуть glTexCoord2d в нужные места.

Альтернативное решение - не использовать gluSphere, а генерировать вершины сферы и текстурные координаты руками, благо это достаточно просто.